# Stay on same page and not empty the cart session during Woocomerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, session, woocommerce, cart

I am in the middle of creating an additional plugin which is a custom payment gateway using the Woocommerce plugin and a child theme to style it.

This is working and I see the payment form correctly and items which is great.
The issue I have is with the payment process option.

The checkout page has an i-frame to the payment solution and is supposed to show only when an order is created and an ID is present. And to make sure we have all the persons details etc.

However the process payment take you to the thanks you page instead.
It also dumps the cart session.

even if I redirect the URL back to the cart page by playing around with it, it still kills the cart.

This would be fine in normal circumstances as I'd expect it to go to a payment page, checkout and be done. But I do not want to do this because this site has to mirror one that is currently live and how that works.

The function in my extended class is this.

```
        public function process_payment( $order_id ) {

        global $woocommerce;

        #$order = wc_create_order();
        ///
        $order = new WC_Order( $order_id ); 

        // Mark as on-hold (we're awaiting the cheque)
        $order->update_status('on-hold', __( 'Awaiting Confirmation of Funds', 'woocommerce' ));

        // Reduce stock levels
        ///$order->reduce_order_stock();

        // Remove cart
        //$woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

        // Return thankyou redirect
        return array(
            'refresh' => true,
            'reload' => false,
            'result' => 'success',
            'redirect' => $this->get_return_url( $order )
        );
        ///return $order_id;
    }
```

As you can see I commented out the bit where to empty the cart and the also the endpoint brings in the thank you template instead of just staying on the same page.

So far I have tried:

- Replicating the code on my checkout to the thank you page and that
  results in an undefined checkout, because the process removes it by
  then
- Changing the end-point reference to the same as checkout
- Creating another page and putting the same shortcode on it

Nothing works, and I have been through the plugin and can see a few things I could do.

- Copy the process_payment function into my extended class and
  effectively re-write it
  or
- Find a filter similar to below that could do what I need

  add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', function(){

  ```
  global $woocommerce;
  $order = new WC_Order();
  if ( $order->status != 'failed' ) {
      wp_redirect( home_url() ); exit; // or whatever url you want
  }
  ```

  });

What I need is it to stay on the same page (refresh) the same way it does when it checks the details to refresh the totals.
Create an order with those current details in and return an order number
Will not kill the cart session at that point, so if I was to refresh the browser for arguments sake it would stay live. (I will work out a way to kill the cart when the person navigates away and a unique session has been created at that point).

Its just this bit I have been fighting with for the past couple of days and not sure the best way.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Andi

Comment: Still Bump! Still fighting this issue months later.The issue is not that it destroy the cart it creates the order but then i cannot access it on the /checkout/ page...

Answer (score 1):

Ok figured this one out.

There is a header action that clears the cart.
We needed to add some more statuses to the array so that it ignores it.

1st remove the action and then add your own method.

```
function st_wc_clear_cart_after_payment( $methods ) {
    global $wp, $woocommerce;

    if ( ! empty( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) ) {

        $order_id = absint( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] );

        if ( isset( $_GET['key'] ) )
            $order_key = $_GET['key'];
        else
            $order_key = '';

        if ( $order_id > 0 ) {
            $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

            if ( $order->order_key == $order_key ) {
               WC()->cart->empty_cart();
            }
        }

    }

    if ( WC()->session->order_awaiting_payment > 0 ) {

        $order = wc_get_order( WC()->session->order_awaiting_payment );

        if ( $order->id > 0 ) {
            // If the order has not failed, or is not pending, the order must have gone through
            if ( ! $order->has_status( array( 'failed', 'pending','pending-st-cleared-funds','on-hold' ) ) ) { ///// <- add your custom status here....
                WC()->cart->empty_cart();
            }
         }
    }
}
function override_wc_clear_cart_after_payment() {
    remove_filter('get_header', 'wc_clear_cart_after_payment' );
    add_action('get_header', 'st_wc_clear_cart_after_payment' );
}
add_action('init', 'override_wc_clear_cart_after_payment');
```